# What other meditation techniques are attributed to Buddha apart from Anapanasati?

Tags: the-buddha, meditation-practicalities, anapanasati, tipitaka

Anapanasati is a meditation technique attributed to Buddha himself and it is from Tripitaka.

What other meditation techniques are present in Tripitaka and are attribited authoritatively to Buddha himself other than Anapanasati?

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha taught 40 meditation subjects. The visudimagga states that Mindfullness occupied with the body(kayagatasati) is taught only in the Buddha's dispensation, not in any other sect.

> Now comes the description of the development of mindfulness occupied
> with the body as a meditation subject, which is never promulgated except after
> an Enlightened One’s arising, and is outside the province of any sectarians.
> (Visudimagga, page 236)

Mindfulness occupied with the body is also mentioned in many suttas.

https://suttacentral.net/an1.575-615/en/sujato?layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=undefined&script=latin

https://suttacentral.net/mn119/en/sujato?layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=undefined&script=latin

https://suttacentral.net/sn43.1/en/sujato?layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=undefined&script=latin

https://suttacentral.net/dn22/en/sujato?layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=undefined&script=latin

https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato?layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=undefined&script=latin

Overall, there are 40 meditation subjects/objects/methods

- Earth Kasina
- Water Kasina
- Wind/Air Kasina
- Fire Kasina
- White Kasina
- Red Kasina
- Yellow Kasina
- Blue/Black/Brown Kasina
- Light Kasina
- Space Kasina
- Recollection of the Buddha
- Recollection of the Dhamma
- Recollection of the Sangha
- Recollection of Sila(virtue)
- Recollection of Dana(Generosity)
- Recollection of Devas
- Recollection of Death
- Mindfulness occupied with the Body
- Mindfulness of Breath
- Recollectionof peace(qualities of Nibanna)
- Perception of a skeleton
- Perception of the bloated
- Perception of a livid corpse
- Perception of the festering corpse
- Perception of the cut up corpse
- Perception of the scattered corpse
- Perception of the hacked and scattered corpse
- Perception of the Bleeding corpse
- Perception of the worm-infested corpse
- Metta(commonly translated as loving-kindness)
- Karuna(commonly translated as compassion)
- Mudita(commonly translated as sympathetic joy or gladness)
- Upekkha(commonly translated as equanimity)
- Perception of Repulsiveness in nutriment
- Four elements(MN 62, MN 28 and AN 4.177). This meditation subject is mentioned in detail in the visudimagga. If it is hard for you to understand, I recommend reading this book. http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/know-see.pdf
  The four elements meditation is mentioned there in a simplified way.
- Boundless space(1st immaterial jhana)
- Boundless consciousness(2nd immaterial jhana)
- Nothingness(3rd immaterial jhana)
- Neither perception nor non perception(4th immaterial jhana)

https://suttacentral.net/an10.29/en/bodhi You can find info about kasinas here. Note:The consciousness kasina mentioned in the sutta is light kasina. The visudimagga explains in detail on how to practice all of the meditation subjects/objects. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

20 meditation topics in bojjhanga samyutta, starting at SN 46.57
https://lucid24.org/sn/sn46/index.html

Using 7sb awakening factors as the basic meditation steps, jhana factors, and framework.

Those twenty meditation objects are "dhammas" that sati remembers, that dhamma-vicaya sambojjhanga takes as the meditation topic to investigate, then passaddhi and viriya use to enter into 4 jhanas with, and that upekkha does insight (equanimous-observation).